# Remember bind on this in react between mutiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, callback

I have a react scheduling application. If a user tries to schedule something within the next 45 hours then I want to throw them an alert message where they can either confirm their chosen timings or change it.

I have a component `Timepicker` which handles the time selection by user and returns `hour and minutes` chosen by the user, as such:

```
renderTimes() {

    return this.props.availabilities.map(function(_av, i) {
    let av = new Date(_av);

    return (
        <a key={i} onClick={this.checkBookingWindow.bind(av.getHours(), av.getMinutes())} className="time-option">
      {_pretty_time(av.getHours(), av.getMinutes())}
    </a>
    );
    }.bind(this));
}
```

The checkBookingWindow function is as follows:

```
checkBookingWindow(hour, minute) {
    var time = new Date().getHours();
    let booking_window = Math.abs(time - hour);
    if (booking_window < 45 && this.state.waive_alert == false) {
        this.setState({open_popup: true});
    } else if (booking_window < 45 && this.state.waive_alert == true) {
        console.log("Waived all rights!");
        //(a) PLAN WAS TO ADD THE CALLBACK OVER HERE!
    } else if (booking_window > 45) {
        console.log("Booking window over 5 hours");
    }
 }
```

Over here if time is less than 45 and if user hasn't waived the alert then it should raise the popup and it's rendered as such:

```
renderWarningPopup() {
if (this.state.open_popup) {
  return(
                <div>
                    <div className="dashboard-modal">
                        <div className="dashboard-modal-header">
                            <span onClick={this.handleCancel.bind(this)} className="icon-cancel modal-close"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="dashboard-modal-body">
                            <p className="small-body-text text-center">Your session is going to happen within the next 45 hours.</p>
                            <p className="small-body-text buffer-bottom-25 buffer-bottom-10-mobile text-center">Are you sure?</p>
                            <div className="schedule-alert-buttons">
                                <button onClick={this.handleCancel.bind(this)} className="btn btn-change-booking">Change Time</button>
                                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} className="btn btn-confirm-booking">Yes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-bg bg-transparent-black"></div>
                </div>
  )}
}
```

Over here on clicking `Yes` the time and date selected by the user earlier should get submitted and I made the following function for the same:

```
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ waive_alert: true});
  this.checkBookingWindow();
}
```

But for obvious reasons it doesn't retain the chosen value of hours and minutes. Is there some way to do this in React?

Before changing the code to raise the alert my `renderTimes()` was as follows:

```
renderTimes() {

    return this.props.availabilities.map(function(_av, i) {
    let av = new Date(_av);

    return (
        <a key={i} onClick={this.props.onSelect.bind(null, av.getHours(), av.getMinutes())} className="time-option">
      {_pretty_time(av.getHours(), av.getMinutes())}
    </a>
    );
    }.bind(this));
}
```

So I was just making a callback which would return the selected `hour` and `minutes`. I want to do the same now at (a) but only after the users select `Yes`

Comment: why not just put the selected hour and minute on either state or just properties on your react class.

Comment: bind does not work like this. calling `bind` returns a new function with the bound context `(this)` and the arguments which needs to be persisted somewhere. Also since you are setting state and the state is available in `this` - as mentioned by @JohnRuddell - what is the harm in putting the hour and minutes in state and accessing the values from the state ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try saving the hour/minute to class variables after it's clicked, and then in `handleSumbit()` you can call `checkBookingWindow()` with those variables:

In the Timepicker component define:
    `let selectedHour, selectedMinute;`

In `checkBookingWindow()`:

```
checkBookingWindow(hour, minute) {
   var time = new Date().getHours();
   let booking_window = Math.abs(time - hour);
   if (booking_window < 45 && this.state.waive_alert == false) {

    /* NEW CODE */
    this.selectedHour = hour;
    this.selectedMinute = minute;

    this.setState({open_popup: true});
   } else if (booking_window < 45 && this.state.waive_alert == true) {
      console.log("Waived all rights!");
      //(a) PLAN WAS TO ADD THE CALLBACK OVER HERE!
   } else if (booking_window > 45) {
      console.log("Booking window over 5 hours");
   }
}
```

Finally, in `handleSubmit()`:

```
handleSubmit(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ waive_alert: true});
  this.checkBookingWindow(this.selectedHour, this.selectedMinute);
}
```

In order to make sure that `handleSubmit()` knows that `this` is the Timepicker component, you'll want to be sure you bind it. It looks like you already do that because you are calling it as `onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}`, so you should be all good. Another way to do that is with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), so instead of `handleSubmit() {}` you'd define it as `handleSubmit= () => {}`. Then you could just put `onClick={this.handleSubmit}`.

Comment: Some other comments mentioned that you could put hour and minute on state, but that's not really necessary in this case because you don't need (or want) to re-render anything when you update the temporary hour and minute variables, and putting them on state could also lead to lifecycle issues because [setState is asynchronous](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3#.iggwyatp6).

Comment: except set state is happening already because he does want to re-render everything.. so he can show the modal.

Comment: True - in this case with the existing code shown, there is no harm in putting hour/minute on state. But I do think it's important to make the distinction that the trigger for re-rendering is `open_popup` changing, not hour/minute changing. By putting hour and minute on state, he'd be opening the door to possible lifecycle bugs if he ever needs to add code to reset or change those variables without re-rendering. There is no reason to put hour and minute on state, and it's generally not a good idea to go adding things to state when they don't need to be.

Comment: @JohnRuddell actually my thoughts are pretty similar to erikamjoh and that's why I didn't want to add it to a state and I've been trying to search online about the same since you guys commented. Not sure yet :/

Comment: except the concept of what the user is doing is associated to a confirmation before submitting the request. I'm just saying its not a problem to add it to state. its not going to be changing since its before submit. You can add it to the class as well if wanted instead of state, just doesn't make a difference in this case

Comment: @anonn023432 adding it to state would be perfectly fine for this use case. if you really dont want to then you can just add it to the class. `this.hour = hour` and `this.minute = minute`

Comment: Yes, the concept of the confirmation action is related to re-rendering, but what if there's a future need to update the stored selected hour/minute *without* rerendering? By adding it to state you're potentially adding technical debt. And it's more overhead and sets a bad precedent for [adding things to state when they really don't need to be](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/09/common-react-dot-js-mistakes-unneeded-state/). I think we both agree that technically you *can* add those variables to state and have it work just fine with the existing code, but I'm discussing what you *should* do.

Comment: Sure I understand what you are saying, I still think it would be ok to add it to state. I have seen the reverse case where forceUpdate() has to be called a lot because of variables that aren't in state. there def has to be a balance between the two. In terms of browser performance unless you are doing things like video (60 fps) set state for this use case wont be a problem.. If you see my comment I posted a while ago on the question I referenced both state and local class variables as a potential solution. both are possible and are viable

Comment: @JohnRuddell that does make sense for my case. I think I would just store it in variables as suggested by erikamjoh to prevent any future problems. But thanks for your help

Comment: @JohnRuddell, good point about forceUpdate(), I agree there def needs to be a balance - anonn023432 should keep this in mind, that if you ever do need selected hour/minute to cause a re-render, you should move them to state rather than calling forceUpdate(). As long as you are aware of this tho, I would lean toward storing it in variables for the reasons I mentioned before. Def agree both solutions are possible and viable.